# Disable Scheduled Publishing in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to disable the scheduled publishing in Umbraco but can't find any settings and can't find any posts mentioning how to do this.

Is this possible within 7.2.8?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit way to disable scheduled publishing that I'm aware of. You can stop it from working by making sure the web server can't resolve it's own address, that will stop scheduled publishing from occurring, but will fill your log files full of errors.

Another option would be to inject a stylesheet into the back office and hide the scheduled publishing fields.

Comment: +1 for the stylesheet option. Might also be possible to change the backoffice view to remove the element, but any update to a newer version of Umbraco could potentially re-enable the feature.